# Indexing deeply nested fields in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

Given a schema like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Darth",
    "mylists": [
      {
        "name": "bucket list",
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "play the harmonica",
            "done": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "shopping list",
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "oil",
            "done": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Luke",
    "mylists": [
      {
        "name": "bucket list",
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "play the drums",
            "done": false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "shopping list",
        "items": [
          {
            "name": "milk",
            "done": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I create an index on name in items. thought it would be:

```
.indexCreate('myItems', r.row('mylists')('items')('name'), {multi: true});
```

tried multi off too:

```
.indexCreate('myItems', r.row('mylists')('items')('name'));
```

but neither seem to return results?

if I stay shallow and try the following it works as expected:

```
.indexCreate('myIndex', r.row('mylists')('name'), {multi: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up with the following:

```
.indexCreate('myItems', r.row('mylists')('items').concatMap(function (x) {return x})('name'), {multi:true});
```